# Converting mongoengine objects to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, python-3.x, flask, mongoengine

i tried  to fetch data from mongodb using mongoengine with flask. query is work perfect the problem is when i convert query result into json its show only fields name.

here is my code

view.py

```
from model import Users
result = Users.objects()
print(dumps(result))
```

model.py

```
class Users(DynamicDocument):
    meta = {'collection' : 'users'}
    user_name = StringField()
    phone = StringField()
```

**output**

```
[["id", "user_name", "phone"], ["id", "user_name", "phone"]]
```

why its show only fields name ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your query returns a [queryset](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=json#module-mongoengine.queryset). Use the `.to_json()` method to convert it.

Depending on what you need from there, you may want to use something like `json.loads()` to get a python dictionary.

For example:

```
from model import Users
# This returns <class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet'>
q_set = Users.objects()
json_data = q_set.to_json()

# You might also find it useful to create python dictionaries
import json
dicts = json.loads(json_data)
```